# Trying to make a static link to create a executable

Tags: c, bash, gcc

I have these libraries: `biblioteca.a` `biblioteca.2` `main2.c` `biblioteca.h` and `biblioteca.c`. I recently created a excecutable with the `main2.c` and `biblioteca.c`. All the files are from the path `/home/Embedded/Class2`.

I use the next command line to create a executable with static library.

```
gcc -o Staticalc main2.c -L</home/Embedded/Class2> -lbiblioteca
```

and it returns this: `bash /home/Embedded/Class2`

also if I take out these symbols `<>` from `-L` and run the following:

```
gcc -o Staticalc main2.c -L/home/Embedded/Class2 -lbiblioteca
```

it returns: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbiblioteca`

Comment: What is a "static link"?

Comment: "it returns this: `bash /home/Embedded/Class2`". What does that mean? is that just the shell prompt? Suggest you paste in the full run log *exactly*.

Comment: For `-lbiblioteca` to work, the static library should be named `libbiblioteca.a`, not `biblioteca.a`.  Or you can just give the path and name of a library file directly, without using `-l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `<>`. These are shell redirections (e.g. `cat /etc/passwd > /tmp/out`)

Instead of:

```
gcc -o Staticalc main2.c -L/home/Embedded/Class2 -lbiblioteca
```

Try:

```
gcc -o Staticalc main2.c -L /home/Embedded/Class2 -lbiblioteca
```

Or:

```
gcc -o Staticalc main2.c --library-path=/home/Embedded/Class2 -lbiblioteca
```